# Как в С++ Builder вызвать функцию из MATLAB?

Tags: c++builder, matlab, c++

Как в С++ Builder вызвать функцию из MATLAB?

Answer (score 3):

Самый простой способ - собрать некоторый код `MATLAB` в `dll`-библиотеку. *Таким образом, код из этой библиотеки можно спокойно вызывать из приложений `C`, `C++`, `python` и т.д.*

Как это сделать, описано [**здесь.**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/compiler/f2-972343.html#f2-1000836)

---

Альтернативный вариант - сделать тоже самое с помощью `MATLAB Automation`, однако, ввиду очевидных причин, такой подход хуже, хотя, возможно и чуть-чуть проще. *Пример такого взаимодействия можно посмотреть [**здесь.**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_external/f15075.html#brgy4zi-1)*