# Как связать Delphi XE с MatLab?

Tags: delphi, matlab

Как связать Delphi XE с MatLab?
Какие есть книги про это? 
С участками кода желательно и объяснением!

Comment: Предполагаю, что эта тема вам немного поможет:

* [Как в С++ Builder вызвать функцию из MathLab?](http://hashcode.ru/questions/45416)

Answer (score 1):

#### Вызов функций `MATLAB` из `Delphi`

---

Помимо способа с компилированием `MATLAB` кода в `dll` и вызова его из `Delphi` очевидным способом *(как я уже отвечал [**здесь**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/45416))*, есть еще способ использовать `COM`-объект `MATLAB`.

Про использование `COM`-объекта `MATLAB` есть подробная информация [**тут**](http://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=call%20delphi%20from%20matlab&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBsQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cpdee.ufmg.br%2F~seixas%2FPaginaSDA%2FDownload%2FDownloadFiles%2FHow%2520to%2520connect%2520Matlab%2520and%2520Delphi%25207.doc&ei=Gd2hTu73Fsad-wab0fyRBQ&usg=AFQjCNHM9JTtUd4wJOubeW_eWXskPri_Tg&sig2=HIq6X3Q-M4RuOKlPROe5ug), однако, лично я из двух способов выбрал бы компиляцию в `dll`, поскольку `COM`-объекты -  это конечно хорошо, но скомпилированную `dll` можно вызвать из любого проекта, и, предположительно, легко перенести *(вместе с пачкой стандартных `dll` `MATLAB'a`)* на другую систему.

#### Вызов функций `Delphi` из `MATLAB`

---

Ситуация ровно диаметральная - компилим `Delphi`-код в библиотеку и вызываем ее из `MATLAB` с помощью функции [**`LOADLIBRARY`**](http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-1ABRP/?solution=1-1ABRP), добавленной с `R2008a`.